# Include controls in a ControlTemplate from another .xaml

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, datatemplate, controltemplate, generic.xaml

I want to create a control which displays an image and a watermark (image or something else) on it.
But the watermark should be loaded from another XAML file in order to let people custom the way the watermark will appear : alignment, opacity, size, nature of the watermark (TextBlock, Image, ...).

For instance I could load my watermark with this appearance

```xml
<Border BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="Aqua" Width="50" Height="50">
  <Image Source="play.png" />
</Border>
```

This code is from my Themes/generic.xaml and *MyWatermarkControl* (inherits from Control) is the class which contain the code of the control (dependency properties).

```xml
<Style TargetType="local:MyWatermarkControl">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyWatermarkControl">
        <Grid>
          <Image Source="{TemplateBinding ImagePath}" />
          <Image x:name="watermark" Source="play.png" /> <!--I want this to be loaded from another .xaml-->
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

My search results lead me to add in my ControlTemplate stuff like ContentPresenter, ContentTemplate, DataTemplate : so many results and I cannot understand how do they work but the fact they are nested

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `Source` property to your `MyWatermarkControl` then bind the `Source` property of your embedded `Image` to this property. For more details see the following tutorial that I wrote:

[A Simple Pattern for Creating Re-useable UserControls in WPF / Silverlight](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2012/02/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight/)